# Subtract img tag from content with Freemarker

Tags: replace, find, freemarker, magnolia

My problem today is the next :
I have to Subtract an image tag "< img src='path  />'" from some content
and after get it i have to Subtract the src attribute and save it in a variable, then
replace it with a php code

This rutine is easy in php but in freemarker is very weird ..
please someone knows hor to do this

thank you !!

Comment: FreeMarker is a template engine. What you want to achieve sounds more like a job for a parser, or at least a regular expression processor. Are you sure you don't abuse FreeMarker? You should maybe do what you describe in Java, and then put it in the model for template processing.

Answer (score 0):

The ?matches built-in will allow you to do regular-expression searches on a given string. It returns a list of substring matches too, so you should be able to get the SRC attribute, put it into a variable, and then build up your PHP code around that.

See the Freemarker manual for details on how to use the built-in:

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches